# How to update array of matrices to glsl shader

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl, vertex-shader

I'm currently working with skeletal animation and I'm really close to getting it working. Currently, I have a struct that has a matrix with 100 spots ( this is so that I can max have 100 joints ) like so :

```
struct skelShader {

glm::mat4 currentJointTrans[100];

};
```

The struct should be binded in the shader, I've done it like this:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &sksBuff);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sksBuff);
// bind buffer to work further with it...
// allocate memory for the buffer in the GPU
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(skelShader), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// because we hard-coded "binding=3" in the shader code we can do this:
// bind Uniform Buffer to binding point 3 (without caring about index of UBO)
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 4, sksBuff);
// good practice, unbind buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
```

sksBuff is just an GLuint.

I fill this array with new values every render/frame that goes by, these values are the new transformations for the joints. I do it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < skeleton.size(); i++) {

    globalSkelInfo.currentJointTrans[i] = skeleton[i]->transformMat[currentFrame - 1] * skeleton[i]->globalBindPosMat;

}
```

This is working correctly for the root joint, but the rest of the joints/mesh remains in bind pose. The problem should be located in where I update the array. Currently I do it like this in the render function after I've done the multiplication for each joint:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < skeleton.size(); i++) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(aShaderProgram, ("currentJointTrans[" + std::to_string(i) + "]").c_str()),
        1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(globalSkelInfo.currentJointTrans[i]));
}
```

After this I draw. The root joints values seem to be moving correctly, but the rest of the mesh is in bindpose and doesn't move. In the Vertex Shader I try to update the matrix like this:

```
#version 440

const int maxJoints = 100;
const int maxWeights = 4;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertex_UV;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertex_normal;

layout(location = 3) in vec4 vertex_weight;
layout(location = 4) in ivec4 vertex_controllers;


out vec2 outUVs;
out vec3 outNorm;

layout(binding = 3 , std140) uniform uniformBlock
{
    vec3 camPos;
    mat4 world;
    mat4 LookAt;
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 MVP;
};

layout(binding = 4 , std140) uniform animationStruct
{
    mat4 currentJointTrans[maxJoints];
};

void main() {


vec4 finalModelPos = vec4(0.0);
vec4 finalNormal = vec4(0.0);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    mat4 jointTrans = currentJointTrans[vertex_controllers[i]];
    vec4 posePos = jointTrans * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
    finalModelPos += posePos * vertex_weight[i];

    vec4 worldNormal = jointTrans * vec4(vertex_normal, 0.0);
    finalNormal += worldNormal * vertex_weight[i];

}

gl_Position = MVP * finalModelPos;
outNorm = finalNormal.xyz;

outUVs = vertex_UV;
}
```

My theory is that the updating of the struct skelShader with my currentJointTrans array is incorrect. Any tips on how I should do this instead?

Answer (score 1):

`glUniform*` calls *cannot* set data in [uniform buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). Indeed, the whole point of uniform buffers is that the uniform data comes from a *buffer object*. That's why you had to create one.

So if you want to set the uniform data for a uniform block, you set that data into the buffer object.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What you said was useful and made me look into it more. I solved it by doing this:

       `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(aShaderProgram, ("currentJointTrans[" + std::to_string(i) + "]").c_str()),
   1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(currentJointTrans[i]));
  glm::mat4 test = currentJointTrans[i];
 }`

Comment: @Haplue: That cannot have solved it because you *cannot set uniform block data through `glUniform` calls*. If that worked, then it would either be because you stopped using a uniform block or by sheer accident. Every one of those `glGetUniformLocation` calls should have returned -1.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry so I forgot to mention that I made the mat4 in the glsl vertex shader to just a unifom mat4, no struct or such. There's been a lot lately so I do hope I didn't forget to mention anything else I've changed. I apologize once again, and thank you!